# Why is $\mathbb{P}(r | s, a, s') = \frac{\mathbb{P}(s', r | s,a)}{\mathbb{P}(s' | s,a)}$?

Tags: probability

Why is $\mathbb{P}(r | s, a, s') = \frac{\mathbb{P}(s', r | s,a)}{\mathbb{P}(s' | s,a)}$? I makes sense to me intuitively but I cannot show it formally. Note that $\mathbb{P}(s' | s,a) = \sum_r \mathbb{P}(s', r | s,a)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the left side is:

$$\frac{P(r\cap (s\cap a\cap s’))}{P(s\cap a\cap s’)}$$

and the right side is:

$$\frac{\frac{P((s’\cap r)\cap(s\cap a))}{P(s\cap a)}}{\frac{P(s’\cap(s\cap a))}{P(s\cap a)}}=\frac{P((s’\cap r)\cap(s\cap a))}{P(s’\cap(s\cap a))}$$

by the definition of conditional probability. Now just remember that a set intersection is both a commutative and an associative operation, and you will see that those two expressions are equal to each other.